# Vertical alignment within table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{9cm}|p{8.2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Control Method}                         & \textbf{Advantages}        & \textbf{Disadvantages}                                                                                            \\ \hline
    Conventional NDI with linear PID-control        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \tabitem The absence of any need for gain scheduling. \\ \tabitem Decoupling between the input-output relations. \end{tabular}                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\tabitem Model and parameters must be accurately known. \\ \tabitem Complete knowledge of the states is required. \\ \tabitem Dual loop design assumes time-scale separation. \end{tabular}     \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Now how can I vertically align the cell containing 'Conventional NDI with linear PID-control'? My table is actually very big, and I will have to make all the entries in the first column vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You have forced centre alignment of your inner tables, but you want top alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{9cm}|p{8.2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Control Method}                         & \textbf{Advantages}        & \textbf{Disadvantages}                                                                                            \\ \hline
    Conventional NDI with linear PID-control        & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}} \tabitem The absence of any need for gain scheduling. \\ \tabitem Decoupling between the input-output relations. \end{tabular}                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\tabitem Model and parameters must be accurately known. \\ \tabitem Complete knowledge of the states is required. \\ \tabitem Dual loop design assumes time-scale separation. \end{tabular}     \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem counterintuitive, but bottom aligning the column works. I have emended your example, including the `array` packaage and changing the table spec to `\begin{tabular}{|b{4cm}|p{9cm}|p{8.2cm}|}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\begin{tabular}{|b{4cm}|p{9cm}|p{8.2cm}|}

\hline
\textbf{Control Method}                         & \textbf{Advantages}        & \textbf{Disadvantages}                                                                                            \\ \hline
    Conventional NDI with linear PID-control        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \tabitem The absence of any need for gain scheduling. \\ \tabitem Decoupling between the input-output relations. \end{tabular}                                                                                                                 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\tabitem Model and parameters must be accurately known. \\ \tabitem Complete knowledge of the states is required. \\ \tabitem Dual loop design assumes time-scale separation. \end{tabular}     \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I run your MWE, the text 'Conventional NDI with linear PID-control' is still not aligned vertically with respect to its cell.

Comment: `b{4cm}` does not produce vertical centering within the cell, but `m{4cm}` does. This functionality is provided by `array`, so @penguinpreferred is correct that you should load that.

Comment: Hmm. I can't explain that. I've added an image to my answer to show what result I get with that exact code.

Comment: I think what's unclear is what @Pietair means by "vertically aligned." I interpreted that to mean "vertically centered" (vertically aligned with the center of cell) which can be achieved using `m{}`. Using `b{}` will cause the text to be vertically aligned with the top of the cell.

Comment: Absolutely. Either could be "correct", depending on what @Pietair means.

Comment: `b` aligns the baseline of the bottom line of the first column with the centre of the table in the second column, it sort of half works if the text in the first column is not too long but if you put a long text in the first column the tables in column 2 and 3 will have big spaces above them as they will align with the bottom line of the first column.